# Using Expect how do I exit foreach function after EOF

Tags: ssh, foreach, tcl, expect

After the following script reads the inventory file and completes the commands from the testcommands file, the foreach function is looking for more information from the inventory file to process and errors rather than ending.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 5

# Open and read hosts from file
set fp [open "inventory_2ps"]
set hosts [split [read $fp]"\n"]
close $fp

# Get commands to run in server
set fh [open "testcommands"]
set commands [split [read $fh] "\n"]
close $fh

# Set login variable
set user "xxxxxxx";
set PW "xxxxxxx";

# Spawn server login
foreach host $hosts {

    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect "$ "

    send "su - xxxxxx\n"
    expect "Password: "

    send "$PW\n"
    expect "$ "

    send "xxxxxx -nobash\r"
    expect "> "

    foreach cmd $commands {
            send "$cmd\n"
            expect "> "

            }
    expect eof
```

Receives error after last host login/exit:

```
>$ spawn ssh xxxxxx@"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ": Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp10 not open
    while executing
"send "su - xxxxxx\n""
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {

    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect "$ "
```

Comment: I don't know why this is a perl question.

Answer (score 1):

According to TCL wiki, the read command will read everything until it encounters EOF. This includes the last newline. In order to discard the last newline you need to add *-nonewline*

Please refer to http://wiki.tcl.tk/1182 for more details.

Let's say we have the inventory_2ps file with 2 hostname lines. "host1" and "host2"

```
$ cat inventory_2ps
host1
host2
```

If we manually run the open tcl command, we get the following

```
$  tclsh
% set fp [open "inventory_2ps"]
file3
% puts [read $fp]
host1
host2

% set fp [open "inventory_2ps"]
file4
% puts [read -nonewline $fp]
host1
host2
%
```

**To Fix:**

Try changing the following lines

```
set hosts [split [read $fp]"\n"]
```

and

```
set commands [split [read $fh] "\n"]
```

to

```
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $fp]]
```

and

```
set commands [split [read -nonewline $fh]]
```

respectively.

Comment: Could you explain your thinking a bit here?

Comment: @alex, absolutely. And because the file contents ends with a newline, when you split on newlines the resulting list ends with an empty element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your code ignores blank values in your input data because they are unhelpful *in your case*.
You do this by adding some trivial filtering at the start of each `foreach` loop:

```
foreach host $hosts {
    if {[string trim $host] eq ""} then continue

    spawn ssh $user@$host
    # ...
```

I often like to use a little bit more complex filtering (as below) as then I can put comments in my configuration files. That is very nice in practice!

```
foreach host $hosts {
    set host [string trim $host]
    if {$host eq ""} then continue
    if {[string match "#*" $host]} then continue

    spawn ssh $user@$host
    # ...
```

Quite apart from this, also make sure that you include a space between the text to `split` and the character set to split by. That might be an artefact of your submission here, and not present in your live code, but it does matter quite a bit as Tcl is sensitive to the difference.